# How to unmarshall a XML without namespace using the Jakarta XML Unmarshaller?

Tags: java, xml, jpa, jaxb, moxy

I am trying to unmarshal an XML into a Java object using the `jakarta.xml.bind.Unmarshaller` but my XML does not contain some of the default namespaces as they are part of the XSD already. How to either explicitly mention to `Unmarshaller` to ignore these default namespaces or add them to the `XMLStreamReader` at the runtime so Unmarshaller can use them?

Following is the XML which fails to unmarshal to Java object:

```
<foo>
    <bar>Hello</bar>
    <test:one>Hello ONE</test:one>
</foo>
```

If I change to this then it would work as expected:

```
<foo>
    <bar>Hello</bar>
    <test:one xmlns:test="https://test.com">Hello ONE</test:one>
</foo>
```

I looked at a few examples on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24387115/7584240) but the provided approach does not work. I do not wish to use an additional library such as Sax rather I want to handler at the XMLStreamReader level or by using the Unmarshaller.

How to achieve this?

Following is the method for doing the unmarshalling of XML:

Main.class:

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, JAXBException {
        final XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, Boolean.FALSE);
        inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, Boolean.FALSE);
        final InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/SampleXML.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("io.convert.test", Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        xmlStreamReader.next();

        while (xmlStreamReader.hasNext()) {
            Object event = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Foo.class).getValue();
            System.out.println(event.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Foo.class:

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
@XmlType(
        name = "Foo",
        propOrder = {
                "bar",
                "anyElements"
        },
        factoryClass = ObjectFactory.class,
        factoryMethod = "createFoo")
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class Foo {
    private String bar;
    
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private List<Object> anyElements;

    void beforeUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
        System.out.println("Before Unmarshaller Callback");
        System.out.println(parent);
    }

    void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
        System.out.println("Before Unmarshaller Callback");
        System.out.println(parent);
    }
}
```

ObjectFactory.class:

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;

@XmlRegistry
public final class ObjectFactory {
  private ObjectFactory() {}
  public static Foo createFoo() {
    return new Foo();
  }
}
```

An error occurred when XML used without namespace:

```
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.2.v202306161219): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,15]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#ElementPrefixUnbound?test&test:one]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.handleXMLMarshalException(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:471)
    at io
.convert.test.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.2.v202306161219): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
```

Based on few response I tried adding the additional class to return the namespaces but that did not work either NamespaceIgnoringXMLStreamReader.clas

```
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;

public class NamespaceIgnoringXMLStreamReader extends StreamReaderDelegate {
    public NamespaceIgnoringXMLStreamReader(XMLStreamReader reader) {
        super(reader);
    }
    @Override
    public String getAttributeNamespace(int arg0) {
        return "";
    }
    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Then using those streams in Main.class:

```
final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
NamespaceIgnoringXMLStreamReader namespaceIgnoringReader = new NamespaceIgnoringXMLStreamReader(xmlStreamReader);
```

I tried adding the `package-info.java` with the following code but still, the unmarshalling without a namespace does not work for me:

```
@XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED)
package io.openepcis.convert.test;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```